# Почему метод reduce не срабатывает как надо при 2х этих вызовах?

Tags: javascript, функции, filter, map-reduce

Метод reduce имитирует метод filter

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.reduce((filteredArr, element) => { 
    return func(element) ? [...filteredArr, element]  : [...filteredArr] 
  }, []) 
}

   dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {return n === 1;});// should return [1, 0, 1].
dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {return n > 2;});// should return [3, 9, 2].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function(n) {return n === 1;}
```

Эта функция ожидает получить аргумент n. Если n === 1 то true иначе false.

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
```

Вот сюда вы её передали и теперь при каждой итерации метода reduce вы передаете текущий элемент из массива.

```
return func(element) ? [...filteredArr, element]  : [...filteredArr]
```

Тоесть в массиве [0, 1, 0, 1] true будет только 1, получается что массив на выходе будет таким

```
[1, 1]
```

Судя по вопросу вы хотите отрезать от массива его часть начиная с определенного начала

Тоесть от

```
[1, 2, 3, 9, 2]
```

Отрезать все что до n > 2;

Получается что бы ваша логика работала нужно в функцию передавать не элемент, а индекс из массива

```
return func(index) ? [...filteredArr, element]  : [...filteredArr]
```

В итоге должно все получится приблизительно так:

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.reduce((filteredArr, element, index) => (func(index) ? [...filteredArr, element] : filteredArr), []);
}

dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {
  return n >= 1;
}); // should return [1, 0, 1].

dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {
  return n > 2;
}); // should return [3, 9, 2].
```

Примечание**: Для таких целей в JS существует нативный метод например slice() который позволяет добится то что вам нужно.

```
[0, 1, 0, 1].slice(1) // should return [1, 0, 1].
[1, 2, 3, 9, 2].slice(2) // should return [3, 9, 2].
```